# PHP is_writable('php://stdout'); returns false, alternatives?

Tags: php, stdout

I have a string and I need to check whether this string represents a writable file or output stream/buffer.

`is_writable()` does not work on stdout, only on real files.

Which method would fit checking `php://stdout` ?

Also tried `stream_is_local()`, but it returns `true` with `php://stdout` aaaand `php://xxx`.

I could obviously try something like this:

```
$file = @fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
if (!$file) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant way?

Comment: Try this: `$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'r');
  print_r($stdout);` Is this what you want?

Comment: Using fopen would work, but I wonder if there is an inbuilt method like `is_writable` for files.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php , php://stdout and php://stderr always access only for write. php://stdin  - for read only

Comment: @ZigZag I know this. I just get a string and want to check whether it is writable at all. I don't know what this string is, it could be anything and my functino needs to reply the correct answer.

Comment: I'm doubtful about being able to find a more elegant solution than simply trying to open the string in write mode.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - You receive a string and you don't know if it's writable? Who, the string? How can a string be writable ?

Comment: @Twisted1919 `bool is_writable ( string $filename )` <--- function takes a `string` as an argument. http://php.net/is_writable

Comment: @DanFromGermany - yes and? you need to decide what that string actually is by looking at it, at how is formatted, if the string equals to php://stdout then you can write in "it", otherwise check if the strings is part of the file system and if it is writable, otherwise return false. There is no such thing as a string being writable, but whatever that string represents is or is not writable.

Comment: @Twisted1919 It's not helpful to argue about the wording I chose for my question. `php://stdout` is a string

Comment: @DanFromGermany - i am not into arguing stuff, i simply don't see why you're having issue with this. php://stdout is a string with special meaning, and core php functions where this can be passed know this.

Comment: PHP has [urlwrappers and streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). If I get one (= string), I need to check if its writable. I can use fopen, but I ask wether there is a different way. Please don't try to comment like me beeing a newbie to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try this below code :

```
is_resource(STDOUT); //true
fclose(STDOUT);
is_resource(STDOUT); // false
```

Comment: if STDOUT is resource, then php://stdout should be available too, I suppose

Comment: Ok. How to check other paths with your method then? Like 'unix:///tmp/someunix.sock'?